# Exact vs Closed Form Solution

Tags: integration

I've derived a closed form expression in terms of elementary functions for a certain function $u(x)$ in the form

$$u(x) =f(a,b;x)$$

where the *a-priori* unknowns $a$ and $b$ are determined from the solution of the pair of nonlinear equations

$$p(a,b)= 0$$

and

$$q(a,b) = 0$$

where the functional forms of both $p(a,b)$ and $q(a,b)$ involve $u(\bar x)$ for specific values $[0,a,b,1]$ of ${\bar x}$, and the definite integrals $\int_0^a u dx$ and $\int_b^1 u dx$

My question is:

Given that $a$ and $b$ have to be determined iteratively, does the **solution** for $u(x)$ still qualify as a closed form solution, on account of the fact that the *expression* for it is in closed form?  Or should I just call it an exact solution?

Comment: Closed form always requires one to say "as a function of what". It's closed form as a function of $a,b,x$ but not closed form as a function of $x$.

Comment: Though it is a little bit unclear here whether $a,b$ are functions of $x$ themselves or if they are just numbers. From what you've said it sounds like they depend not just on $x$ directly but even on $u$. This would make this quite far from a closed form solution.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ depend on $u$, which you seem to be saying, it's not what I would call a solution, let alone a closed form solution.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are not functions of $x$. The functions $p(a,b)$ and $q(a,b)$ contain $u(a)$ and $u(b)$ and the definite integral of $u(x)$over specific limits.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I was clumsy in my wording. The functions $p$ and $q$ contain $u$ evaluated at specific values and the definite integral over specific limits. I've modified the OP accordingly.

Comment: @Ian, I've clarified the OP. In any case, I think your comment basically answered my question.